# Why application not getting application closing events?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

In Windows Phone 8, when I press start button, I should get `Application_Deactivated` and `Application_Closing` events. But when I set break point in these events, breakpoint doesn't hit. Why `Application_Closing` and `Application_Deactivated` are not getting called?

[Please refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.deactivated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`Occurs when an application stops being the foreground application.`

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="ContineousLocationTracking.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContineousLocationTracking" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"
            RunningInBackground="PhoneApplicationService_RunningInBackground" 
            />
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Comment: Is there any code within these methods? Because if they are empty, the compiler can remove them.

Comment: How are you setting up these events?

Comment: @xmashallax No I have code in events

Comment: @CathalMF I am adding in `<shell:PhoneApplicationService>` of App.xaml

Comment: Actually You cannot Handle those events by setting a breaking point and freeze your device, those are just events when the application goes dormant mode or tombstone mode. As you may know, the only physical button you can stop from going out is the back button. other buttons are not available for coding.

Comment: @gayan1991 Thanks. `the only physical button you can stop from going out is the back button.` I was not knowing this. Secondly, I am not stopping start button, I just want to handle these events.

Comment: what do you mean by handle? you wanna resume the application to its current state or you wanna move to different pages ?

Comment: @gayan1991 By handling I mean, I want to perform some task on these events.

Comment: you can handle anything but ui elements simply...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47842/discussion-between-pranitkothari-and-gayan1991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you put into `Deactivation` enent should be called. I would suggest to read [Application lifecycle at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). There are a lot of information, so I won't post it here.

You can surely set breakpoint at Deactivation event (according the disscusion in comments).

But Closing event is not called when you hit Start buton.

More usefull links:

- [Windows Phone 8 Application Lifecycle](http://iamabhik.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/windows-phone-8-application-lifecycle/)
- Understanding the Windows Phone Application Execution : [part 1](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/16/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-2.aspx), [part 3](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx).

---

If you are having problems check you App.xaml if those events are used:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

And it wouldn't get called (instantly) if your App is set to run in Background (Location tracking). It can get called in [specific circumstances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: `Deactivation` event is also not getting called.

Comment: Did same thing, but bp doesn't hit.

Comment: @pranitkothari is this your App.xaml, can you show it whole?

Comment: But your app is running in background it isn't deactivated. Try to remove that line and see if then works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47843/discussion-between-pranitkothari-and-romasz)